# Activation Curl on EasyPHP

Tags: php, apache, curl, easyphp

After uncommenting the curl-modul in the php.ini i get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5617x160120145639\ext\php_curl.dll' - Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 24):

This as, Anar Hariyev states, works:

> 100% working solution, I won this problem!
>
> 1) Copy libssh2.dll from php directory to Windows/system directory
>
> 2) In php.ini #zend_extension remove (;) front row ;extension=php_curl.dll
>
> 3) Restart Apache server.

However, you can copy libssh2.dll into Apache's bin folder as opposed into the Windows System directory. This keeps the server portable.

Comment: This seems a much better solution than adding to windows system directory.

Comment: is " In php.ini #zend_extension remove (;) front row ;extension=php_curl.dll" supposed to mean "remove '#' from line '#zend_extension ' and remove ';' from line  ';extension=php_curl.dll' " ? Anyway it does not work for me

Comment: what if i cant find libssh2.dll in easyphp?

Answer (score 6):

100% working solution, i won this problem!

1) Copy libssh2.dll from php directory to Windows/system directory

2) In php.ini #zend_extension remove (;) front row ;extension=php_curl.dll

3) Restart Apache server.

Answer (score 3):

The Solution was to copy the files from the php directory:

- libeay32.dll
- libsasl.dll
- ssleay32.dll

to "C:\Windows\System"

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 32-bit version of EasyPHP and the 64-bit version of Windows, the solution is to copy the files below (from the EasyPHP PHP folder):

- libeay32.dll
- libsasl.dll
- ssleay32.dll

to the folder: `C: \ WINDOWS \ SYSWOW64`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your php directory in the path (environment variable)