# Activate cURL with EasyPHP

Tags: php, apache, curl, easyphp

I'm trying to launch a php script which needs curl. I'm using Easyphp for the first time.
I tried to uncomment the line `extension=php_curl.dll`in php.ini. But it still doesn't work. Even after a restart.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you have to check if the extension gets loaded. First check the http servers error log file after restarting it, then the output of the legendary script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is the server error log : `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\\eds-binaries\\php\\php704vc14x86x160521084858\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - Le module sp\xef\xbf\xbdcifi\xef\xbf\xbd est introuvable.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Yes, I just checked and the file is well placed.

Comment: Seems it contains a dependency that does not really make sense. Is that file really bundled with your installation or did you grab it somewhere? Looks a bit like a miss matched architecture or similar...

Comment: It's a fresh install, and no I didn't grab this dll somewhere :s

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. I suggest you address the easyPHP distributor or their forum. They should be able to help.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2):

I'm in similar situation where I removed the ";" before the cURL extension in php.ini, restarted the webserver however cURL still did not enable.

I'm using EasyPHP 16.1 (PHP 5.6.19 x86, Apache 2.4.18 x86).

My search ended when I found solution below.

1. Copy libssh2.dll from php directory to Windows/system directory
2. In php.ini #zend_extension remove ; front row ;extension=php_curl.dll
3. Restart Apache server.

**My PHP directory where libssh2.dll resides:** C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5619vc11x86x160731090901

Now it's working and can confirm by printing all loaded extensions using:

```
<?php

print_r(get_loaded_extensions());

?>
```

Reference:
https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/curl-on-easyphp-devserver-16-1/5134/6

Comment: You don't necessarily have to copy the lib to your `Windows/system/` directory. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38530865/1617737 .