# Unable to activate Curl on Easyphp Devserver 16.1.1

Tags: apache, curl, easyphp, devserver

I am trying to activate curl on my Easyphp Devserver 16.1.1, but I keep getting the error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5619vc11x86x160615094909\ext\php_curl.dll' - Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato [cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory].\r\n in Unknown on line 0

I did the following:

1. un-commented "extension=php_curl.dll" in both php.ini files
2. verified that the file php_curl.dll actually exists in extension_dir
3. copied libeay32.dll, libsasl.dll, ssleay32.dll to c:\Windows\System\, c:\Windows\System32\, c:\Windows\SysWOW64\
4. Downloaded cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and added the full path to it on curl.cainfo in php.ini
5. Downloading various versions of curl from https://curl.haxx.se
6. Set paths to php directories in My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables  (eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5619vc11x86x160615094909\)
7. I rebooted after doing all these steps (specially for the step #6)

There are at least 5 similar questions, I followed every suggestion but nothing worked. Apache continues not to see my dll. Can anybody help on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but for people who land here and want skip all of the useless steps of Lucian.
Just use the answer from Anar Haziyev on this link:
[Activation Curl on EasyPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905939/activation-curl-on-easyphp)

work on easyphp devserver.

Comment: I did all @Lucian P. did but,as for him, it does not work for me, also the answer you linked, which by the way is weird because maybe comes from multiple copy/paste and hence contains this nonsense: "In php.ini #zend_extension remove (;) front row ;extension=php_curl.dll". I have Windows 10, EasyPHP and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with EasyPHP and what it fixed is that I had to install PHP as a different instance, not in the EasyPHP build and started the PHP service from the command line.